# Remove object from a list in python without changing the index

Tags: python, numpy

I have a list that can be simplified to something like this:

```
x=[6,5,4,3,0,0,0,2,1]
```

I want to be able to remove the zeros but keep the indexes, so that when I plot `x` the values are not offset to the left.

I used the numpy.delete fonction like this:

```
def zeros(array):
b = []
for j in range(len(array)):
    if array[j] == 0:
        b.append(j)
    j += 1
c = np.delete(array, [b])
return c
```

Here's the plot that I obtain:
[See how the red curve offsets to the left after all the zeros?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K518R.png)

How could I get around this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x=np.array([1,2,3,4,0,0,0,5,6]).astype(float)
index=np.linspace(0,x.size-1,x.size)
x[x==0]=np.nan #find where x==0 and replace with NaN, which wont show up on graph
plt.plot(index,x,'*')
```

Comment: That's it! I didn't know the fonction np.nan. thank you!

Comment: This works because `plot` is setup to ignore/blank these `nan` (not a number) values.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can remove all zeros from list. Use a list comprehension for that.

```
>>> x=[6,5,4,3,0,0,0,2,1]
>>> x = [y for y in x if y != 0]
>>> print x
[6,5,4,3,2,1]
```

It should work.

Comment: Yes. My problem is when I plot it. It isn't the same to plot "x" when for example the value "2" corresponds to the index 7 than when it corresponds to the index 4.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using Pandas for that:

```
In [69]: a = pd.Series(x)

In [70]: a
Out[70]:
0    6
1    5
2    4
3    3
4    0
5    0
6    0
7    2
8    1
dtype: int64

In [71]: a.loc[a!=0]
Out[71]:
0    6
1    5
2    4
3    3
7    2
8    1
dtype: int64
```

[plotting](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html):

```
a.loc[a!=0].plot()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x = [1,2,3,4,0,0,0,5,6]   
x_without_zero = [a for a in x if a!=0]
print x_without_zero
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

If the elements are unique in list:

```
indexes_for_x_without_zero_in_x = [x.index(b) for b in x_without_zero]
print indexes_for_x_without_zero_in_x
[0, 1, 2, 3, 7, 8]
```

else:

```
x = [1,1,3,4,0,0,0,5,1]
zip(x, range(0, len(x)))
[(1, 0), (1, 1), (3, 2), (4, 3), (0, 4), (0, 5), (0, 6), (5, 7), (1, 8)]
[c for c in new_x if c[0]!=0]
[(1, 0), (1, 1), (3, 2), (4, 3), (5, 7), (1, 8)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can form a an index list for example like so:

```
from operator import itemgetter

t, xprime = zip(*filter(itemgetter(1), enumerate(x))) 
t
# (0, 1, 2, 3, 7, 8)
xprime
# (6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1)
```

This uses `enumerate` to get an index and then `filters` based on the original list.